# Preferring shortest possible types

Tags: c, optimization

The overwhelming advice seems to be to prefer `int`s in C unless space is important (http://c-faq.com/decl/inttypes.html).

Wouldn't it make more sense to tend to use the shortest type possible?

Shorter types have an obvious advantage in large collections -- the collection will take less space with the shorter type.

In numerical functions, `int`s have an advantage as it should be faster for the CPU to work with them, but isn't it then the job of the optimizer to swap in an `int` when I declare a `short` on the stack with which I then proceed to compute?

I've tried compiling a couple of numerical functions, once with shorts, and then with ints, and I got identical output assembly at -O3 (shorts are 2 bytes and ints are 4 on my architecture) so it would seem that the int advice is no longer valid, especially considering the potential for space savings which should matter more than ever considering the widening CPU/memory performance gap. (I think it's rather common to have data structures that are used both numerically and in large collections).

Are there any reasons why I shouldn't tend to default to the shortest possible type?

Comment: The assembly can't have been identical: if nothing else, one would have needed to convert the data to the other type.

Comment: @ScottHunter I tried something like `$t compute_${t}($t a, $t b)
{
    $t sum = 0;
    for($t i; i<30; i++){
       sum += a+2*b; 
    }
    return sum;
}
` and it got reduced to `lea    0x1(%rsi),%eax
imul   %eax,%edi
imul   $0x1e,%edi,%eax
retq   
` in both cases. I guess if everything happens in registers, then no conversions are necessary.

Answer (score 3):

You should stick to the standard `int` because it's the size that the machine can most easily work with. Other sizes require extra instructions or special instructions, and those instructions take more space.

You say you're getting identical output assembly with -O3, but I would check that very closely, for example I would run a *diff* between the assembly language output files.

If you have a *large number* of the integer values, such that the data space difference exceeds the program size difference, then consider shorter values.
Even then, only worry about that if storage size is actually a problem.
Usually it isn't.

Comment: The first test I tried got compiled to happen purely in registers so there indeed was no difference. When I tried to apply that function on an array, the `short` version was slightly different as expected. I still wonder how the increased CPU time due to the added instructions will be offset by the decrease in memory access at different working set sizes. It's well possible the increased relative memory access of time of new hardware could have rendered the old advice obsolete, but to know, I think, would require some extensive benchmarks.

Comment: @PSkocik: I don't know if you're assuming, as lots of other programmers do assume, that this code you're concentrating on will actually account for a significant fraction of total execution time, of the app that contains it. I'm sure you're aware of the [*streetlight effect*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Streetlight_effect). Usually when I do performance tuning, there may be several large speedups available that I could never have guessed ahead of time, followed by some tight code like yours that originally took around 1% of time, that's worth attention only after the others.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the comments from Mike regarding sticking with the native size. I understand you question from the hardware perspective (it should be a matter of which bytes are enabled on the bus).

If you have a 32-bit bus but decide to use 16 or 8 bit integers, you may be imposing a pack/unpack cost on your processor.  Some older RISC processors I have worked with only want to fetch 32 bits at a time.  So if you want to update a byte, it has to read the whole 32 bits first, then it needs to mask out the byte of interest.

By all means, do the testing with your target compiler and optimization settings.  If you do see a difference in 32 versus 16 or 8 bit integers, see if your compiler can give you an interlist and that will let you see how the compiler is handling the short(er) integers.